# .Net Core - Passing id to partial view, partial view needs to get more data from id and show results

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I'd like the partial view to get more data based on passed through value: `id`

This is how I'm passing the value to the partial view:
`@Html.Partial("_Customer", "123")`

From `_Customer` partial view, I'd like it to access a sql server view I've created

```
+-----+------+-----+
| Id  | Name | Age |
+-----+------+-----+
| 122 | Jim  | 35  |
+-----+------+-----+
| 123 | Elon | 47  |
+-----+------+-----+
```

And grab the Name & Age, and display it on the partial view input boxes.

Wondering if there's an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a service and inject in partial view, for example -

Service

```
public interface IUserInfo
    {
        User GetUserInforById(int id);
    }

    public class UserInfo : IUserInfo
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _cotext;

        // Inject DbContext 
        public UserInfo(MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _cotext = dbContext;
        }
        public User GetUserInforById(int id)
        {
            return _cotext.Users.Single(i => i.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

Partial View

```
@inject SeedSample.Services.IUserInfo UserInfo

@{ 
    var information = UserInfo.GetUserInforById(Model.Id);
}

@*write your html code*@
```

Comment: Basically I would just enter `@information.age` & `@information.name` in the html?

Comment: Yes, for example <label> Age: </label> @information.age

Answer (score 1):

View components are similar to partial views, but they're much more powerful. View components don't use model binding, and only depend on the data provided when calling into it.

Refer to the following steps:

1.Create `CustomerDetailsViewComponent` class in the `ViewComponents` folder which is created in the root path

```
    public class CustomerDetailsViewComponent:ViewComponent

    {

       private readonly MVCDbContext _context;

       public CustomerDetailsViewComponent(MVCDbContext context)
       {
          _context = context;
       }

       public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int customerId)
       {
          var model = await _context.Customer.FindAsync(customerId);
          return View(model);
       }
    }
```

2. The View component search path : `/Views/Shared/Components/CustomerDetails/Default.cshtml` ,the default view name for a view component is Default, which means your view file will typically be named Default.cshtml. You can specify a different view name when creating the view component result or when calling the View method.

```
@model TestProject.Models.Customer

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Age" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Age" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

3.To use the view component, call the following inside a view:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("CustomerDetails", new { customerId= 123})
```

For more details on View Components , you could refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: What if I want to put the age or name value in a telerik drop down, would it look like this? `.value(TestProject.Model.Customer.Age)`?  https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/dropdownlist/index

Comment: What do you exactly  mean ? From your original demand , _get more data based on passed through id_ , the result is  a single data rather than a collection. Why do you want to  put them in a DropdownList ?

Comment: let's say i have 3rd column `customer type` and there's a dropdownlist for `customertype`,  Elon has `customertypeid = 1`.. how would i fill that in telerik's drop down list value? (this basically does a select on the dropdown list).